# Changing color of answers

Tags: javascript

I've a simple quiz program. If user clicks the answer, color change on yellow. I would like implement two things:

1. Remove color after clicking second time
2. Toggle color if user choose other option

I'm trying to add removeEventListener to my changeBg() function but it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
 [Codepen](https://codepen.io/matoung/pen/wXNpLq)
```

Comment: what is the purpose of removing the event listener, which event do you want to stop listening for?

Comment: I want to change color on transparent if I will click second time on the same button. changeBg function change color on yellow when user click first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order to toggle the others, you need a way of grouping them.

You can, for example, add a `data` attribute, like `data-q="1"` to say this is question 1.

Then, you can loop through all the question one options.

```
function changeBg() {
  // Check which question this is
  let question = this.dataset.q; 
  // Get all the other options from this question 
  let others = document.querySelectorAll('[data-q="' + question + '"]');

  // If the background color is already set
  if (this.style.backgroundColor) {
    // Clear it
    this.style.backgroundColor = null;
  } else {
    // Otherwise, clear all of the options
    for(var i = 0; i < others.length; i++)
      others[i].style.backgroundColor = null;
    // Then set the one that has been clicked to yellow
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; 
  }
}
```

Here is  a fork of your [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKgxaO) to show it in action for the **first question**